# Use a not active application (background)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there any way to work with minimized or not active applications? Can I open my application, then open and use another, and press a button that will activate my program?

For example, open my application, open Safari, press a button (F1 or any other), my program copies a `NSString` and pastes it to the text field I am using in Safari. I know how to make my program do what I need (copy and paste a message when the button is pressed) when it's active but it somehow has to be done in the background.

Comment: I think you should read something like this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/

Comment: @stosha - Not sure an iOS doc will help with an OSX problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your application should provide a "service". That will be accessible from contextual menus, the Services submenu of the application menu, and can have a hot key assigned. It is designed to (optionally) receive the currently selected data from the app which invokes it and (optionally) return new data to replace the selection or be inserted at the insertion point if there's no selection.

See the [description of Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Services.html) from the OS X Human Interface Guidelines.

See the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).